# How can I show recent posts from same taxonomy as the post currently being viewed?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, recent-posts

I'm wondering how I can show recent posts from the same taxonomy as the post that's currently being viewed (working with custom post types and custom taxonomies).

If it was simply a category of a regular post, it would look like this:

```
<?php global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
?>
<h3>More News From This Category</h3>
<ul>
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=20&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<li><strong><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id);?>" title="View all posts filed under <?php echo $category->name; ?>">ARCHIVE FOR '<?php echo $category->name; ?>' CATEGORY &raquo;</a></strong></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But with custom posts/taxonomies, there has to be a different sort of solution. Couldn't find anything useful so far in the wordpress codex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)?

Quick-and-dirty, from your code example:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'some-term' );
foreach ($terms as $category) :
?>
<h3>More News From This Category</h3>
<ul>
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=20&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<li><strong><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id);?>" title="View all posts filed under <?php echo $category->name; ?>">ARCHIVE FOR '<?php echo $category->name; ?>' CATEGORY &raquo;</a></strong></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

See also: [`the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) and [`get_the_term_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Answer (score 1):

To get the terms (from a custom taxonomy called `'my-taxonomy-name'`) associated with to a post with ID `$post_id`:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'my-taxonomy-name' );
```

That returns an array of term objects. (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)) Pick the first one, say:
    $term-slug = $terms[0]->slug;

And then query using `get_posts`, it accepts our taxonomy as a key (see

```
$args = array(
   'numberposts' => 20,
   'my-taxonomy-name' =>  $term-slug 
);
$posts = get_posts ( $args );
```

See the [Codex on custom taxonomies and get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Custom_Post_Type_Category_.28Taxonomy.29)

Comment: Heh, our answers dropped at almost exactly the same time, and are almost exactly the same. So, upvote for you. :)